# findassoc function in tm package of R giving error

Tags: r, text-mining

I have a term document matrix build from youtube comments

about 977 documents

created a term document matrix using:

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(doc_corpus)
```

and then on applying the function

```
findAssocs(dtm,"hello", 0.6)
```

getting the following (translated from french)

```
Error in which (x [term],> corlimit): index out of bounds
```

all the other functions are working like findFreqTerms and hclus etc

Comment: check if the word esixt in the terms...something like `'hello' %in% Terms(dtm)`, what do you get ?

Comment: the word doesn't exist and for existing words it's working. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an error beacause the word does not exist in the terms sets. You can check this using :

```
'hello' %in% Terms(dtm)
```

which should return FALSE.

Comment: thank you. this works. i wish there was a better exception handling for this one.

Comment: You could contact the author(s)

Comment: @codious or put this  in simple `trycatch`.